# How do you create many-to-many class instance relationships in JRuby w/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, jruby

I have this basic setup:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'foo_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :bar_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos
end
```

Now I can see all the bars associated with foos using `Foo.first.bars` or `Bar.first.foos` and this works as expected.

Where I'm stumped is how to do something like this:

```
foo_rows = Foo.all
=> (all those rows)
bar_rows = Bar.all
=> (all those rows)
foo_rows.first.bars.find { |bar| bar.bar_id == 1 }.some_col
=> "The value from the database"
bar_rows.find { |bar| bar.bar_id == 1 }.some_col = 'a new value'
=> "a new value"
foo_rows.first.bars.find { |bar| bar.bar_id == 1 }.some_col
=> "a new value"
```

But instead that last line says `"The value from the database"`

How do I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bar_rows` and `foo_rows.first.bars` are arrays with different objects in memory. Just because the `id` attribute of one of their elements is equal, it doesn't mean they're the same objects:

```
bar_rows.find { |bar| bar.bar_id == 1 }.object_id
# => 40057500
foo_rows.first.bars.find { |bar| bar.bar_id == 1 }.object_id
# => 40057123
```

You are changing attribute of one of these objects, there is no reason that the attribute of the second object should be changed.

As for the `JRuby` part, it does not matter -- MRI would behave the same.

Comment: Yeah, that explains the behaviour.

Is there a way to get the desired effect?

Comment: It's difficult to say what's your desired effect. You can either modify one of `foo_rows.first.bars` or modify the one from `bar_rows`, add it to `foo_rows.first.bars` and delete the previous one.

Comment: I'd expect the bar with the id of 1 to be the same bar that's associated with all the foos, just as it would be in a relational database.  

This way I can locate a bar through a foo, update it right there, and not have to traverse every foo looking for that bar to update it as well.

Comment: I don't think there's any way around it. You'll have to find the object directly in the associations of given `foo`. If you change the object somewhere else and want to have the changes reflected in `foo`, you'll have to reassign the associated item.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, hah!  I guess I'll be writing some methods to do that all quick-like.  Thanks!